# Postman won't start on Windows 7

Tags: postman

I've been using Postman for a while now. Suddenly though it has stopped working. When trying to open it I get a loading spinner then nothing. No error. Nothing in Event Viewer. Nothing. Although the Icon in the task bar at the foot of the page looks broken or corrupted.

I've tried reinstalling, rebooting, clearing cache - nothing

I'm on Windows 7, 64 bit

Anyone ran into anything like this? :-/

Comment: I think your shortcut is corrupted. This has happened to me in the past. Delete the shortcut and create a new one that points to the actual app. Postman comes as a browser extension as well. Maybe try that one until you figure out what went wrong with the other version.

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 7.  There are a lot of threads on their support site about this issue, but no evidence of anyone getting their issue resolved.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. The solution that worked for me is to use `--disable-gpu` flag for postman shortcut `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Postman\<app-version>\Postman.exe --disable-gpu`:

[image]

More info on Github: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4594

Comment: This solution worked for me after opening postman and getting a black screen; I have uninstalled the app/ restarted my PC multiple times but nothing solved my problem except this one; It worked like a shine thank you @feeeper

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened for me when running a remote desktop session, it appears that postman is running but opening off screen.  According to this thread 
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2833
This can happen when you add or change a monitor.
There is a solution there - deleting some json files - but I found that I could see the Postman app in Task Manager -> Applications and then bring it up by selecting "Switch To"

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and found that you need to navigate to AppData\Local\Postman and find the latest installed version folder now change the shortcut path on the desktop in my case it was AppData\Local\Postman\app-7.36.0\Postman.exe I did and it worked :)

[postman folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLtLF.png)

[postman desktop shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0GJX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Windows 10. The application did not show up after opening it. [This post](https://conetrix.com/blog/fixing-an-application-that-appears-in-task-bar-but-doesnt-open) helped me:

1. Hover the Postman icon in the taskbar. Then click the preview window that opens above it.
2. Press Alt + Space and then M or click "Move".

[image]

3. Move the Postman window with arrow keys, it probably was invisible on the right or left side of your screen.

This problem appeared after working with an external display. When I got Postman back visible, it showed an update dialogue.